# How to call PHP script from another PHP script?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script, say `a.php`, which is called from JS using Ajax (this is a POST request and some data is passed to the script).

I have another PHP script, say `b.php`, from which I would like to call `a.php` and pass it some data. I expect `a.php` to do the job just like if it was called from JS.

I don't want to do `include('a.php');` because of possible collision between variable names.

How could I do this ?

Comment: I tackled this problem a little while ago... ultimately I chose a different approach because there were just too many compromises.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471930/how-to-sandbox-a-request-to-another-php-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why aren't you just putting these together as functions, using an include, and calling them like you would in C++ or something? [Global is bad.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable)

Answer (score 2):

One solution (if imperfect) is to use `file_get_contents()` with a URL.

So, something like:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/a.php?this=that&that=this');
$json = json_decode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call it over HTTP with [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).  But I think you should consider a redesign.  Whether you code procedurally or with OOP, you should be able to have a multi-file program without collisions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 5.3 you could use [Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) to avoid your variable name collision issue.

Another suggestions would be to refactor your code so that you could include the file and then call a function to execute it. All variable inside a function call only have a scope of the function.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to intiate a server request from `b.php` with the URL for `a.php` that is normally used by the client.